# Why NestJS controller level ExceptionFilter using @UseFilters(new XXXFilter()) wont work if there is global one in useGlobalFilters in app level?

Tags: javascript, exception, nestjs, httpexception, nestjs-config

I defined two custom `HttpExceptionFilter` one used in global and one in controller api level.
But when I debug I found that controller level one will always be skipped. Is there way we can allow both filter functional? Because I want to further customize and add additional error codes when http failed in certain controller endpoints or with specific http exception for a specific controller when thrown.

Is this even possible using NestJS? Is there an alternative? Am I approach this wrong?

In global:

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter(), new ConflictErrorFilter());
```

In controller:

```
@UseFilters(new ControllerHttpExceptionFilter())
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  @Post('/:id/dothing')
....
```

CustomException Filter and ControllerHttpExceptionFilter

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse<FastifyReply>();
    const { statusCode, error, message } = exception.getResponse() as Record<
      string,
      any
    >;

    void response.status(statusCode).send({
      status_code: statusCode,
      message: [].concat(message),
      error,
      error_code: 'PLAYROUND'
    });
  }
}


@Catch(HttpException)
export class ControllerHttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse<FastifyReply>();
    const resp = exception.getResponse();
    const { statusCode, error, message } = resp as Record<
      string,
      any
    >;

    void response.status(statusCode).send({
      status_code: statusCode,
      message: [].concat(message),
      error,
      error_code: 'PLAYROUND controller'
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Odd, the [documentation states](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#filters) that filters resolve in order of route handler to controller to global.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I added the relevant code, do u see any issue how I wrote it?

Comment: when the first filter already catches the exception and returns the response(no error/exception), will the second one will have an error to catch? I am not sure but if you want both to execute try throwing the exception back from the first one.